# Minimize form when minimize button is clicked in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have a form which is maximized with this property:

```
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
```

and with `FormBorderStyle = None`. This means that when this form is opened, it can not be minimized, which is the behavior I want.

From this main form, there is a button which open another small form called 'Console' where I can see some messages thrown by the main form. This 'Console' form is with `FormBorderStyle = FixedSingle`, and this means that can be minimized.

The problem with this, is that when I minimize the 'Console' form, I can not opened again because the main form occupy the whole screen.

What I am trying to do is to minimize the 'Console' and be able to see it to maximize it again when I wish.

I tried to use events of the 'Console' form like `SizeChanged` or `KeyUp` and control when the minimize button is pressed.

All things I tried have gone wrong, and always when I press the minimize button, the form minimizes normally.

It is possible when I minimize the form by clicking on the minimize button, to see the minimize window down to maximize it when I want?

I accept any suggestions!

Comment: Well, you'll have to decide how you want to approach it.  "to see the minimize window down to maximize it" does not mean anything.  You have a button, consider using it to restore the window.  Or just don't permit minimizing it at all.  Or close the window when it gets minimized.  Or give it a taskbar button.  Or use a docking layout manager.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I've used this option: when I click to minimize, I just relocate the form and resize it. Maybe is a simple and manual option and for sure it will be better ways to do it, but this gives me what I need for now.

@HansPassant thanks for your help! I am going to look for information about docking layout manager as you suggested.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub frmConsole_Move(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Move
    If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
        Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(247, 0)
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        Me.Location = New Point(padre.GMapControl.Location.X, padre.GMapControl.Location.Y + 1000)
        Me.TopMost = True
    ElseIf Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized Then
        Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(447, 900)
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        Me.Location = New Point(padre.Location.X + padre.GMapControl.Width * 0.9, padre.Location.Y)
    End If
End Sub
```

I've used some buttons location of the main form to locate the 'Console' form, but it can be any value.

Thanks!

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).